# Sublime Text и индексирование

Tags: javascript, sublime-text

Как заставить саблайм индексировать проект на js?

т.е. например, при объявлении

```
var locals = require('./gulpfile.locals.js');
```

и конструкция вида `locals.` предлагала бы список доступных параметров включенных через `require`

Пробовал SublimeCodeIntel, но с js он походу не дружит.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У Sublime Text, к сожалению, нет возможности "подхватывать" javascript файлы и использовать их ресурсы подобным образом.

Из решений могу предложить использовать [WebStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/), который, увы, платный,но обладает необходимым Вам функционалом. Имеется 30-и дневная триальная версия. Если подобный функционал Вам необходим - можно задуматься и о покупке.

Comment: спасибо за ответ. Про вебшторм знаю, как раз ищу ему замену.

Answer (score 0):

Есть проект [Exuberant Ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/), который индексирует исходный код и позволяет текстовому редактору быстро оперировать элементами языка. JavaScript тоже поддерживается, но встроенная по умолчанию версия считается немного устаревшей. Для "современного" JS есть версия от Mozilla - [mozilla/doctorjs](https://github.com/mozilla/doctorjs). Встроить это в Sublime Text 2/3 можно с помощью плагина [SublimeText/CTags](https://github.com/SublimeText/CTags). Честно признаюсь, сам пока не пользовался, просто наслышан, так что не могу с уверенностью говорить о возможностях этого проекта.

Кстати, в Sublime Text 3 из коробки встроена индексация ([статья в блоге](http://www.sublimetext.com/blog/articles/file-indexing)), установив курсор на элемент языка и используя опцию *Goto ⇒ Goto definition* (<kbd>Alt + D</kbd>) можно перейти к его объявлению. К сожалению фича не очень удобная, по крайней мере по отношению к JS. Например поиск объявлений функции будет проходить по всем файлам проекта, включая файлы библиотек, и искать она будет все функции с таким же названием, и вместо прямого перехода будет предложен список всех возможных файлов, где встречается объявление данной функции. Возможно файлы можно добавлять в черный список, но я не уверен.

Answer (score 0):

EMACS + js2-mode + [TERN](http://ternjs.net/doc/manual.html) Позволяет автокомплит через js-анализатор, однако необходимо настроить `.tern-project`.

Для sumbime также [существует плагин tern](https://github.com/marijnh/tern_for_sublime), попробуйте его.